# GDB core backtrace Bogus addresses

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, coredump, backtrace

When I compile the same code with g++ with -o2 flag I can backtrace successfully without any Bogus adresses. Like:

```
0x08156079 in CItem::GetValue (this=0x3adb0f00, idx=0) at item.cpp:957
0x081b123c in quest::item_has_flag (L=0x3af9bdc0) at questlua_item.cpp:155
0x08363cba in luaD_precall (L=0x3af9bdc0, func=0x3b1cedd8) at ldo.c:249
0x0836ba86 in luaV_execute (L=0x3af9bdc0) at lvm.c:637
0x08363fad in resume (L=0x3af9bdc0, ud=0xffffa164) at ldo.c:337
0x0836393b in luaD_protectedparser (L=0x3af9bdc0, z=0x8363f80, bin=-24220)
....
```

But I need to use g++48 (with c++11) for better performance and other reasons... So, when I do same thing with -o3 optimize flag and g++48 I can't get any file names etc. Like:

```
#0  0x28a56f3c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00000032 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  0xbfbf9838 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x28a4ea3a in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00000032 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00000004 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00000001 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x28a70694 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0xbfbf969c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x28a6b06c in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Which flags I must not use for debugging? (-fno-omit-frame-pointer) Which flags should I use for debugging? And for which reason?

Comment: Code with -O0 until the behaviour is correct.  GDB will work much better. Then consider optimization.  If your performance is insufficient, you probably should search for better algorithm(s).    On ubuntu 12.04, I have been using '-gstabs+'.

Comment: I tried -O0 and result is same, I can't see exactly. Why is that happening.

Comment: I do not recognize the "No symbol table info" (though I have seen something similar).  If you also tried the '-gstabs+' option (on all of your compilation units) with no luck, there are a number of other debug options ... . the simplest being -g, and others include -gcoff, -ggdb, -gstabs, -gstrict-dwarf, -gxcoff.  See man g++, debugging options.

Comment: Don't use `gdb` on binaries compiled with `-O` and without `-g` (at most optimize debugged binaries with `-Og`  and preferably without it)

Comment: First of all you need the latest gdb. Which version are you using? Which version of gcc? Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am on FreeBSD  9.2, x86. Binary compiled with -g flag, and Debugger version is; 6.1.1. Still I have this problem. Here is flags : `# Standard Setting
LIBS = -pthread -lm -lmd
# Removed -fno-rtti 
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O2 -m32 -pipe -fexceptions -D_THREAD_SAFE -DNDEBUG
CFLAGS += -mtune=i686 -fstack-protector-all -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib32/mylibs -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-local-typedefs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gcc 4.8 you can use -Og switch, to enable all optimizations that do not interfere with debugging.

Also make sure you enabled debug info (-g switch). If you updated your compiler to newer release, you should also update the debugger. Another thing you may try is to make sure gcc generates debug info in compatible format (try -gdwarf-2 or similar).

Comment: `-Og`  should be used *with* `-g`